# Are there real; EIP-4844 transaction? Anyone has an example?

Tags: eip-4844

I would like to understand how EIP-4844 would affect miner reward. In EIP-1559 base fee per gas and max fee per gas have been introduced, and base fee is burned, while actual fee - base fee goes to the miner (or validator is better term since the merge).

EIP-4844 introduces `max_fee_per_blob_gas` and consecutively blob base fee. There will be separate blob gas market, and blobs will be stored in consensus layer. [This writing](https://www.blocknative.com/blog/eip-4844-blobs-and-blob-gas-what-you-need-to-know) says that blob fees will co-exist with EIP-1559 `max_fee_per_gas` and `max_priority_fee_per_gas`. Then how miner's reward will be calculated for EIP-4844 transaction? I assume blob gas logic will be the same as regular gas logic - base fee is burned, everything above it goes to the miner. Will there be regular gas price and blob gas price? See actual transaction would help immensely - anybody is aware of one?

Answer (score 0):

I'll use this [transaction](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x0f8c63e3c10157c3aceddcbfbed059067e3ad50c96184d2f3bc327f737bc736e) as an example for demonstrating my understanding of this upgrade.

According to [eip-4844](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-4844.md),the blob data fee would be deducted from the sender balance before transaction execution and burned.
[image]

The balance change for the sender in the tx is 0.004271970890799872.
[image]
The value sent is 0 and the fee paid by sender is 0.000702320486112.
So in that case, the blob fee here is 0.004271970890799872 - 0.000702320486112 = 0.003569650404687872

I used the code in the eip and get the same result here.
[image]

For block producer reward, according to the explorer balance change,
[image]
[image]

The max_priority_fee here is 1e-09 so in that case, it only includes max_priority_fee reward not blob fee(same as eip-1559).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).